# please help me in writing my sql query for this

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, outer-join

table 1 : -

```
name | location | Area | Region | Country
-----------------------------------------
abc    8          6      9        12
```

table 2 : -

```
lid | lname | aid | rid | cid
def    8       6     9    12
```

table 3 : -

```
aid | aname | rid | cid
6      ghi     9     12
```

table 4 : -

```
rid | rname | cid
9      jkl     12
```

table 5 : -

```
cid | cname
12     mno
```

how can i join these 5 tables in mysql and retrive " abc, def, ghi, jkl, mno ";

Answer (score 0):

I hope This will work for you.

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.lname ,table3.aname,table4.rname,table5.cname 
FROM table1 
WHERE 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.lid = table1.location
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.aid = table1.area
LEFT JOIN table4 ON table4.rid = table1.region
LEFT JOIN table5 ON table5.cid = table1.country
```